# Understanding textrange in C# WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have three lines of code. Which is an example of textrange. I am trying to understand these lines of code. But I am totally stuck in it.

```
TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(box1.Document.ContentEnd,box1.Document.ContentEnd);
rangeOfText1.Text = chbx1[i].ToString();
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

Comment: What do you think it currently does? Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange(v=vs.110).aspx) too.

Comment: @veleous I think, it is appending the single character at the end of richtextbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TextRange rangeOfText1 = new TextRange(box1.Document.ContentEnd,box1.Document.ContentEnd);
```

Creates a new `TextRange` object called `rangeOfText1` which contains a content selection specified by the two `TextPointers` provided to its `constructor`.

```
rangeOfText1.Text = chbx1[i].ToString();
```

Replaces the `Text` content of the `rangeOfText1` `TextRange` object with the content of `chbx1[i].ToString()`.

In your example you are creating a `TextRange` starting and ending at the end of your `box1` control effectively selecting nothing, so the above code has the appearance of appending text.

```
rangeOfText1.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```

Applies the specified formatting to the content of `rangeOfText1`, in your example setting its `foreground` property to `Red`.

Comment: So main theme is that, it is appending the single character at the end of richtextbox, and then changes its color to red.Am I right  ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that it is appending the value of chbx1[i] to box1 (which I assume is a RichTextBox) and using a red foreground color to display that text (from chbx[i].