# C# - UWP: How to get TextRange object?

Tags: c#, uwp

In a `WPF` app, we can get `TextRange` as follows (or see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20273775/1232087) or examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview)):

```
var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
```

**Question**: How can we achieve the same for a [RichEditBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_RichEditBox_Document) in a `UWP` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string text;
richEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out text);
Windows.UI.Text.ITextRange range = richEditBox.Document.GetRange(0, text.Length - 1);
```